# undefined symbol: fmemopen when cross-compiling with Android NDK clang

Tags: c, android-ndk, llvm, stdio

I'm attempting to compile a (rather old) C program to Android ARM64. I've gotten most things working but one function seems to be giving me trouble:

```
ld: error: undefined symbol: fmemopen
```

I have included `stdio.h` in my program which should have it available. I've read elsewhere that fmemopen is a Linux thing and that some other platforms (maybe Android?) don't support it. Anyone know if that's true? Other functions of stdio.h (fopen, for example) seem to compile just fine.

Comment: `fmemopen()` [is POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html).

Answer (score 2):

`fmemopen` is right there in `stdio.h`:

```
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 23
FILE* fmemopen(void* __buf, size_t __size, const char* __mode) __INTRODUCED_IN(23);
#endif /* __ANDROID_API__ >= 23 */
```

As the include guards indicate, you need to compile for at least android version 23.